# Taking HTML content from other URL pages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my app to take text from other web pages!

If I insert the word "computer" I want to go to the URL of Cambridge's website and to take data I need.

```
insertingNewWord(insertedWord){
    var pageHTML = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/"+insertedWord;
    var definition = pageHTML.getElementByClasName("def-head");

    return definition;
}
```

Any idea how I could take any tag by Class or ID name from another page, and printed in my app.
If I get a solution in ReactJs that would be even better.

Comment: If you're doing this in node and are open to using a package,  this is a popular one that works the same as jquery.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: Read this about get requests here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Comment: You have to use API for this purpose https://dictionary-api.cambridge.org/api/demo

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an `<iframe>`

```
<input type="text"><input type="button" value="search dictionary"><br>
<iframe width="400" height="300"></iframe>
<script>
  const [input, button] = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    iframe.src = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/" + input.value;
  })
</script>
```